# How can I tell my form that the value of a control changed?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to implement an MVC type pattern in my Eclipse plugin, but I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to have my controls tell the form that they belong to that they have changed. There's no `isDirty()` method and no `firePropertyChanged()` method like I am using in the form/editor relationship.

Comment: What form are you talking about? Is this the `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets` form?

Comment: My form extends `FormEditor` and my specific page extends `FormPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FormPage` derived class you add form page parts based on `SectionPart` or `AbstractFormPart` or `IFormPart` which contain the controls for the page.

`AbstractFormPart` has a `markDirty` method (also `markStale`, `refresh` and `commit`) which are intended to be the main ways to manage the form state.

Comment: Thank you! That looks like just the direction I needed.

Comment: Right now, all my controls live directly in the `FormPage`. You're saying I need to create either a `SectionPart` or an `AbstractFormPart` that contains my controls, and set _that_ as the content for the `FormPage`? Do you know of any tutorials or documentation for this?

Comment: Yes controls go in one or parts on the page. These forms are called 'managed forms', there is a little bit on them in the help, some in the Javadoc and bits and pieces on the web. You can also look at the source of the PDE plugin.xml editor which uses this extensively.

Comment: Does the FormPart need to have specific listeners set for the controls, or is that done automatically when the control is added to the part?

Comment: If you mean to call `markDirty` you have to do that.